# 'str' object has no attribute 'label' when validating

Tags: django, django-templates, django-validation

Okay, this is a weird one, at least to me.

I have a form that contains `event_date` and `article_date`. 
I want to confirm that `event_date` is not bigger than `article_date`, because that would mean that the event would take place in the future, which is not possible.

Now, what I did is this:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        event_date = cleaned_data.get("event_date")
        location = cleaned_data.get("location")
        article_date = cleaned_data.get("article_date")

        if event_date and location:
            cleaned_data['relevance'] = True
        else:
            cleaned_data['relevance'] = False
            raise forms.ValidationError("You need to supply at least Event and Location information")

        if event_date > article_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This event would be in the future...try again.")

        return cleaned_data
```

(I include the other validation to show you that validating works otherwise)

In my template, I have the following code to display form errors:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {{form.non_field_errors}}
{%endif%}

{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.errors %}
        <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, when I try to test if this works and submit a date in the future, I get the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'label'
Error during template rendering, error at line 62:

57                          {% if form.non_field_errors %}
58                          {{form.non_field_errors}}
59                          {%endif%}
60                          
61                          {% if form.errors %}
62                          {% for field in form %}
63                          {% if field.errors %}
64                              <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
65                              {% endif %}
66                          {% endfor %}
67                          {% endif %}
```

If I comment out the validation, the error disappears.

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

EDIT:

By request, my view, in all its glory:

```
def assignment(request, pk):
"""View for each assignment"""
if request.user.is_authenticated():

    #### Get correct articles
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    country = assignment.country.cowcode
    start_date = assignment.start_date
    end_date = assignment.end_date
    articles = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date)).distinct()

    #### Pagination ####
    paginator = Paginator(articles, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator(page(paginator.num_pages))

    # Check if on first page and enable redirect
    if page is None:
        current_page = 1
    else:
        current_page = page
    redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page

    ##### Show already created events on the page
    current_article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
    EventFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventRecord, can_delete=True, exclude=('coder','article','url','last_updated'), extra=0)
    event_queryset = EventRecord.objects.filter(article__id=current_article.id).filter(coder=request.user.id)
    coded_events = EventFormSet(queryset=event_queryset, prefix="event_form")
    article_date = current_article.pubdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    try:
        last_updated = ArticleHistory.objects.filter(coder=request.user.id).filter(article__id=current_article.id).order_by('-pk')[0]
    except:
        last_updated = None
    ##### Create Forms    
    CodingFormSet = formset_factory(CodingForm,can_delete=True, extra=0)

    ###### Get correct locations
    location_queryset = Geonames.objects.filter(cowcode=country).order_by('name')

    if request.method=='POST':

    ##### Check if coder wants to go to next page or stay
        if "coding_form_next" in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")

            next_article = True
            if formset.is_valid():

                process_form(formset, country, request, current_page, paginator, next_article, coded_events, location_queryset)

                if articles.has_next():
                    current_page = int(current_page) + 1
                else:
                    current_page = int(current_page)

                redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            insert_article_pubdate(formset, current_article)


        elif "coding_form_save" in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")

            next_article = False
            if formset.is_valid():

                process_form(formset, country, request, current_page, paginator, next_article, coded_events, location_queryset)

                update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)

                redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            insert_article_pubdate(formset, current_article)

        elif 'add_event' in request.POST:

            cp = request.POST.copy()
            cp['coding_form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp['coding_form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1

            if int(cp['coding_form-TOTAL_FORMS']) == 1:

                formset = CodingFormSet(cp, prefix='coding_form')

            else:
                formset = CodingFormSet(cp,prefix='coding_form')
            #insert_article_pubdate(formset, current_article)
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)


        elif 'save_changes' in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(prefix="coding_form")
            changed_events = EventFormSet(request.POST, prefix="event_form")
            instances = changed_events.save()


            try:
                history_record = ArticleHistory.objects.filter(article__id=paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0].id).filter(coder=request.user.id)[0]
                history_record.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
                history_record.save()
            except:
                history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
                article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
                article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
                article_history.coder = request.user
                article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
                article_history.save()

            EventFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventRecord, can_delete=True, exclude=('coder','article','url','last_updated'), extra=0)
            event_queryset = EventRecord.objects.filter(article__id=current_article.id).filter(coder=request.user.id)
            coded_events = EventFormSet(queryset=event_queryset, prefix="event_form")

            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            insert_article_pubdate(formset, current_article)
    else:
        formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST or None, prefix="coding_form")

        update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
        insert_article_pubdate(formset, current_article)

else:
    print ERROR
return render(request, 'coding/assignment.html', 
{'articles':articles,'assignment':assignment,'formset':formset,'coded_events':coded_events,'last_updated':last_updated})
```

EDIT 2:
And here the full form, as per request:

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="form"> 
            <div id="organizer">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset %}
                <div class="form-container">
                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                    {{form.non_field_errors}}
                    {%endif%}

                    {% if form.errors %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%"><label for="id_form-0-event_date">Event Date:</label></td>
                            <td class="datepicker">
                                {{ form.event_date}}
                            </td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-location">Location:</label></td>
                            <td><div class="location_wrapper">{{ form.location }}</div></td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-actors">Actors:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.actors }}</td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-num_participants">Number of Participants:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.num_participants }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-issue">Issue:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.issue }}</td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-side">Side:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.side }}</td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-scope">Scope:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.scope }}</td>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-part_violence">Participant Violence:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.part_violence}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="id_form-0-sec_engagement">Security <br/> Forces Engagement:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.sec_engagement }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><label for="id_event_form-0-DELETE">Delete Event:</label></td>
                            <td>{{ form.DELETE }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div id="form-nav">
                <div id="add-event">
                    <input type="submit" name="add_event" value="Add Event"> {{ dings|date:'Y-m-d'}}
                </div>
                <div id="save-stay">
                    <input type="submit" name="coding_form_save" value="Save">
                </div>
                <div id="save-next">
                    <input type="submit" name="coding_form_next" value="Save &#38; Next">
                </div>


            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you share your view, too?

Comment: this looks rather complex ;), just a shot in the blue, in one of your forms in your formset there is no formfield but rather a string... but this is like stating the obvious, sorry I cant help any further atm...

Comment: The full form would probably be helpful here.